# WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

```
$replace_order = new WC_Cart();
$replace_order->empty_cart( true );
$replace_order->add_to_cart( "256", "1");
```

The above code add product `256` to the Cart `1` time. But the issue I'm having is that I want to be able to completely override the product price... as far as I can tell, the only thing I can do it apply a coupon to the Cart.

Is there a way to completely override the price to something totally custom?

Comment: Check this link very usefully https://www.cloudways.com/blog/change-woocommerce-price-display/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here is the code for overriding price of product in cart

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        // for WooCommerce version 3+ use: 
        // $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have quite a bit of experience with WooCommerce?

Comment: This updates the cart. But still in the quick cart icon at the top it displays actual product price. Any hooks?

Comment: Yup, does work with variations. Use $cart_object->cart_contents[$key]['variation']['variation-name'] tho, as there's no "set" method for variations

Comment: Hey, could you please give me an example on how to make it work? I want to add the product with ID 598 to cart with an overrided price. I tried your code but don't know where should I put the product ID. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like these two answers should be combined.

Comment: hey there, i tried your solution but what i'm trying to do is add custom price for each product when added to cart.
I guess your solution iterate over added cart items. Any help you can do ?

Comment: Sorry to nag, but this doesn't seem to work in the latest version of Woo Commerce (currently 3.0.4). I had to use `$value['data']->set_price($custom_price);` because it appears the inner workings of `WC_Product_Simple` has changed.

Comment: Added comment about API change in WooCommerce version 3 to the answer, so it's more discoverable.

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P faced your issue in 2018 :) any solution/hook to update price in mini cart/quick cart ? it is showing old price which is set using `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter

Comment: This solution doesn't work in current Woocommerce versions. You can use `$value['data']->set_regular_price($custom_price); && $value['data']->set_sale_price($custom_price);` instead. Which I think is easier and intuitive.

Answer (score 47):

You need to introduce an `if` statement for checking product id, in above code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    $target_product_id = 598;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        /*
        // If your target product is a variation
        if ( $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Add this code anywhere and make sure that this code is always executable.

After adding this code, when you'll call:

```
global $woocommerce; 
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(598);
```

Only this product will be added with overridden price, other products added to cart will be ignored for overriding prices.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: How can I set a custom price based on user input? This custom price is hard coded. Any suggestions? Something like function add_custom_price( $cart_object, $custom_price )

Comment: how can i dynamically get the target product id of the product of which add to cart button is clicked?

Comment: Seems like these two answers should be combined.

Comment: @ratnakar-Ratnakar-Store-Apps  your code added the product but when goto cart page its price reset

Comment: @AbhishekKumar did you find any way for those id's ? i would like to add custom price for each product added

Comment: $target_product_id = 598;
$custom_price = 10; 
need to make this dynamic, how can do that ?

Answer (score 14):

I have tried all above code samples and latest woocommerce 3.0 is not support any of the above example. Use below code and working perfectly for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custom price  
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Try my example above.

Comment: Have you tried the exact code? I have this running in a live premium plugin with 1000's of installs. Which version of WooCommerce do you have installed?

Comment: Latest version Both WP Version 4.7.3 and woocommerce 3.0.1

Answer (score 7):

After release of woocommerce version 3.0.0 product price is update on add to cart using set_price($price) function. The example is given as below :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'mj_custom_price' );

function mj_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
   $woo_ver = WC()->version; 
   $custom_price = 10;
   foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value )
   {
       if($woo_ver < "3.0.0" && $woo_ver < "2.7.0")
       {
           $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
       }
       else
       {
           $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
       }
   }            
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For the Wordpress and Woocommerce latest version,Please use like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $custom_price = 5;
        $value['data']->set_price($custom_price); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For eveeryone that got here from Google. The above is now deprecated as i found out updating to WooCommerce 3.0.1.

Instead of the above you now need to use `set_price` instead of `price`

Here is an example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps people in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

With WooCommerce 2.5 I found this to be a 2-part process.    The first step is to change the run-time display of pricing when added to the cart via the woocommerce_add_cart_item filter.    The second part is to set the persistent session data which is read during checkout via the woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session filter.   This seems to be faster than hooking the calculate totals filters (such as woocommerce_before_calculate_totals) as they are run very frequently in WooCommerce.

More details here:
[woocommerce change price while add to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731118/woocommerce-change-price-while-add-to-cart/35632566#35632566)

Comment: is it possible to add each product's custom price in cart rather than iterating over added cart products ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how i did it, first i add my custom price to cart_item_data witch can save custom data to cart items, then i use woocommerce_before_calculate_totals, loop the cart and add the previously added price.

```
function add_donation_to_cart() { 

    $cart_item_data = array('price' => $_REQUEST['donate_amount']);
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( 5395, 1, '', array(), $cart_item_data);
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    foreach ( $cart->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $value['price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, where you use add_donation_to_cart function ?

Answer (score 1):

To make it dynamic ( override price for each item in cart separately ), you need to save the override product price in session with cart item key as session key using `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook.

by using these session values you can calculate correct Cart Total and make the altered price appear in the Order Item as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'kd_custom_price_message' );

function kd_custom_price_message( $price ) {

        $textafter = ' USD'; 
        return $price . $textafter;
}
```