# Alter Cart Contents for Specific Product Type in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In this question  [WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override) we can alter the price for all products in the cart.

What I need is to alter only products with Specific custom type called 'auction' and not change the rest of products.

Here is the code I use::

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

I tried::

```
if ( $value['product_type'] == 'auction') {
   $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I rememeber correctly, `$value['data']` is the product object.

So you should be able to use the `is_type()` method:

```
if( $value['data']->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
  // a simple product
} elseif( $value['data']->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
  // a variable product
}
```

Don't forget that you can always use `var_dump( $cart_object )` or better still `error_log( json_encode( $cart_object ) )` (requires `WP_DEBUG_LOG` be enabled) to get a look at what is in the variable.

Comment: You are right, but this doesn't work for custom product type and I don't know way! Can you help me?

Comment: If this is correct (I couldn't test it because I was busy) then it should work just fine for a properly created custom product type. Please edit your question to share more of your code. Also, please confirm you tried the `is_type()` method which is very different from the code you posted in your question.