# Woocommerce Mini Cart Widget product price override

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to change product price in Woocommerce Mini Cart Widget? I've overrided price in cart using tips from [WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override) but it only works for cart page. Prices in widget are not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" you can use "woocommerce_cart_item_price" filter, some thing like

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price','modify_cart_product_price',10,3);

function modify_cart_product_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
    $price = wc_price($custom_price, 4); 
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set price to 0 for free products:

```
function set_free_items_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

     $returned_item_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

     if (isset($cart_item['free_item']['value'])
         && $cart_item['free_item']['value'] == true) {
         $returned_item_price = 0;
     }

     return get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $returned_item_price;
}
```

I hooked inside class, so it hook looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'set_free_items_price', array(__CLASS__, 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_filter'), 10, 3 );
```

But if you are using it as procedural function, your hook should look like this:

```
add_filter( 'set_free_items_price', 'woocommerce_cart_item_price_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Keep in mind this is also affecting *price* row in regular cart. 
And, if you are not seeing changes in mini cart, try to *update cart* on regular cart page, and the go back and check again if mini-cart values has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

To change the price on the WooCommerce Mini Cart Widget you have to use this filter hook: **woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity**

You can check the line 63 of the file: *[woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/mini-cart.php#L63)* to see how the filter hook is created.

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

As the name of the filter hook indicates it can be used not only for the price but also to show the quantity.

For example you can use it to apply a discount to certain products based on a condition. In this case I used a value stored in the meta data of the product.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 'custom_wc_widget_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );

function custom_wc_widget_cart_item_quantity( $output, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
  $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
  // Use your own way to decide which product's price should be changed
  // In this case I used a custom meta field to apply a discount
  $special_discount = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'special_discount', true );
  if ($special_discount) {
    $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
    $final_price = $price - ( $price * $special_discount );
    // The final string with the quantity and price with the discount applied
    return sprintf( '<span class="quantity">%s &times; <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">%s <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">%s</span></span></span>', $cart_item['quantity'], $final_price, get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() );
  } else {
    // For the products without discount nothing is done and the initial string remains unchanged
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Note that this will only change how price is displayed, if you have to change it internally use also this action hook: **woocommerce_before_calculate_totals**