# WooCommerce Fixed Coupon Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce, and how create two fixed price for one product ?

1. standard price product
2. coupon using fixed price

If user enter coupon code, will show coupon fixed price, else standard price.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming problems (but down to configuration / choosing the right plugins). It should be migrated to Wordpress.stackexchange (ref. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309587/3235496)

Answer (score 0):

When you use coupons in woocommerce you can set if you want to deduct a percentual or a fixed amount. You can also limit to certain products only. 
So you could basically assign a coupon to the one product with a fixed discount value.

Comment: hmm, ok. Bun any suggestion ? How create two prices, and if i using coupon, show only second price ?

Comment: You would need to do some custom coding.. add a cuatom field for your discount price input field.. then during checkout if coupon applied check for matching products and replace the price of the matching product with this snippet http://stackoverflow.com/a/21227830/515114

Answer (score 0):

i've found this plugin while browsing around.. maybe it could help to get the job done
(I'm not affiliated to that company/developer)
http://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/#override-price-wc-fields-factory