# Cart total not updating with overridden cart prices

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have been overriding the price of products dynamically based on specific criteria, but the ajax and mini-cart doesn't seem to see the price change when the product is getting added in the cart.  It shows the original price total.  I can override the prices in the cart itself no problem, but you have to be on the cart or checkout page to see it.  Not sure what approach to take.  I felt as though I've tried everything.

Seems as though `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()` is called to display current cart total, but it doesn't seem to run `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_add_discount');` hook when called. 
If you go to the actual cart page, it is the proper pricing.

This code added will display the right individual price but not the subtotal.  You have to refresh the cart page by clicking on the Cart URL for it to update the $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() object.

I've also tried `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 'woo_add_discount');` which does the same thing.. you have to refresh the page after loading.   I'm sure I'm not the only one who had overriden prices and can't get all the peices to fall into place.

I've tried this and see that the second comment down on the answer, someone is having the same issue but no answers.
[WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this myself.   I tried Paul de Koning's answer.  Changing to apply_filters caused the prices to go to $0.  I think this is because the order they need to go in.

Here was my solution.  The root cause was that I was using the change price_html function to provide the change prices for the cart. Inside that function there were add_action calls etc.  Somehow, there must have been an ordering issue.   This is a multi step process to ensure all areas are done correctly.

If you want to change woocommerce prices without using sessions to store the changed price for the cart while changing the display price and hiding prices, perform something like the following:

**functions.php**

```
    add_action('woocommerce_get_price_html','special_price');

    function special_price($price) {

       //put any if statements for hiding the cart button and discounting pricing below and return true or false
       $displayprice = true;
       $alterprice   = true;

       if($displayprice === true) {

         add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10, 2);
         add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_action', 10);
         add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_checkout_action', 10 );

       } else {

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10, 2);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'woocommerce_template_single_product_add_to_cart', 10, 2);        //   
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

        //return blank or something like 'Signup to view price'
        return '';

       }

       //if you are displaying the price (altered)
       if($displayprice === true && $alterprice === true){

         $price = price_manipulator($theid);
         return $price;

         //display add to cart and price

       } 

       //if you are displaying the price (unaltered)
       return $price       

     }


    function price_manipulator($theid = '') {

      if(empty($theid)){
        $theid = get_the_ID();
      }

      $product = wc_get_product($theid);

      //30% off example
      $newprice = floatval($product->price * (1-0.3));

      return $newprice;
    }

   /*version of pricing if you are adding something to cart*/
    function special_price_cart($theid){

              $price = price_manipulator($theid);             

              return $price;

    }


    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'woo_add_discount');
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 'woo_add_discount'); //this is if you are using the mini-cart woocommerce widget

    function woo_add_discount() {

       global $woocommerce;    

       //create if statements same as if you were displaying the price 
       $displayprice = true;


       if($displayprice === true){  

         foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 

           $price = special_price_cart($cart_item['data']->id);
           $price = str_replace('$','',$price);
           $price = str_replace(',','',$price);               


           if($price > 0){

             $cart_item['data']->price = floatval($price);

           }    

       }

     } 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `apply_filters` instead of `add_action`