# Woocommerce- Different prices for same product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am creating an eCommerce store for a relative's business. He has products that the user must personalize on the website. I am coding a separate page that will allow the user to do this, that will link back to the store and add the item to the cart when they are done. 
I found a solution to add each product to the cart separately, instead of adding to the quantity (since each product added has been personalized), and a solution to change the price of items in the cart.

[WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override)
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-separate-cart-items-product-quantity-1/

The problem is that all the items are changed, not just the last one added.
For example: User designs a ballpoint pen with her name on it. The price is $4. The user then designs a gel pen with her name. The cart will show two separate pens with an increased calculated price, but the price will increase for all pens, not just the last one added. I need to find a way to set the price for the last item added, based on the price sent from the product building page. So far, nothing I've tried has worked.

Variable products won't work for this site.

```
//To display a product separately every time it is added 
function bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    $unique_cart_item_key = uniqid();
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );


//To change the item price programmatically. Changes all items with the same ID
//I need it to change only the last one added.
//Set to retrieve new price from the customizing page

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);
/**
 * @param $cart_obj
 */
function add_custom_price($cart_obj ) {
    ob_start();
    include 'createbb.php';

    global $custom_price;
    $target_product_id = 17;
    //  This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value['product_id'] == $target_product_id) {
            $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
        }
    }
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about your implementation of WooCommerce and attempt to integrate products as Variable.

Comment: I added the code. I don't know how to price each separate "pen" individually when they are customized by the user, since they all share the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of functionality you are looking for is actually so common that it has a name "Product Options" (this is different to variations). This feature allows you to add configurable add-on's to the price of a product through a design on the edit product page. In a lot of eCommerce platforms like OpenCart you have this sort of functionality built in for free, however Automattic opted to keep it as a separate bolt on which they charge for:

https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/

Before you say it yes it is annoying that they charge for it, really this is such a common thing for people to request you can tell that it was a calculated decision to monetise it. And yes it is still very possible to program everything bespoke, but you are inevitably re-inventing the wheel for no reason other than to avoid paying for the feature (there are free versions of the plugin above that others have made, google is your friend).

Consider something, what if Automattic change their hooks in the future? you'll have to modify your code, assuming you find out before it borks the site. What if you wish to change options, or you need someone else to change them and you are not around?

If you weigh things up, you'll find the best option in the end is either to grab the official plug-in, or use one of the free alternatives. Trust me I am doing you a favour.

Koda

Comment: Thank You. I considered these types of plug-ins, but didn't purchase only because the site has a very specific look and feel that I don't know if I'd be able to achieve with this. I did buy one that ended up being a waste of money. They wanted it to be a step by step process that's interactive for the customer, but I maybe I could work around that.

Comment: You can, especially the official one as they come with templates that can be overridden like the templates you get for the rest of WooCommerce. The part you really don't want to have to re-code is the admin side of things because it'll either take you too long to implement, or it won't be an adequate stand in for the ones already available. I am not doubting your ability, just purely pulling from experience.