# Woocommerce set fixed cart price based on number of items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to modify the total price of the cart to £10.00, ONLY if there are 4 items in the cart. If there are 3,5,6,7 etc...do not apply the discount rule.

I'm having problems with the below snippet.

1. Firstly the discount triggers no matter what number of items are in the cart even after explicitly defining the count
2. I can't figure out how to set the price of the cart to be £10.00, I can only apply a discount based on amount of items.

Can anyone offer some assistance please?

```
// Hook before calculate fees
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

/**
 * Add custom fee if more than three article
 * @param WC_Cart $cart
 */

$taster_item_count = 4;

function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count == $taster_item_count ){
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the amount to reduce
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.1;
    $cart->add_fee( 'TASTER BOX DISCOUNT APPLIED', -$discount);
}
```

Comment: you want to set the Total cart to 10 pound no matter how much the products cost is  only if there is 4 items?

Comment: @kashalo yes, correct

Comment: @kashalo - Did you manage to think of a improved solution to the above?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override Had to use the newer hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`

Comment: i have deleted my answer as this question is marked as duplicated and that's why i didn't work on it again

Comment: I have solved and linked answer to what helped me solve :)

Comment: Great to hear that :)